# how to change div visibility on addeventlistener click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have a html `div` which normally is hidden, I also have a button with  an `addEventListener` on click for it. Now what I want is that when the user click on the button I want the `div` visibility to turn `visible`, before I tell you my problem here is my script:

```
<div class="Takeapicture_div">
    <input type="button" class="takeapicture_btn" id="takeapicture_btn" value="Take a picture"/>
</div>
<div class="takeapicturesnap_div">
    <video id="video" class="profilevideo" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <input type="button" id="snapButton" class="takesnapshoot" value="Capture Image"/>
</div>
```

Div CSS script:

```
.takeapicturesnap_div{
position:fixed;
visibility: hidden;
left:400px;
top:40px;
height:600px;
width:600px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
border-radius:2px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 3px 1px #ddd;
overflow:hidden;
background:white;
}
```

EventListener for button:

```
document.getElementById("takeapicture_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
var takeapicdiv = document.getElementById("takeapicturesnap_div");
takeapicdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
}, function(stream){
    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
}, function(error){

});
});
```

As you can see in my button eventlistner I have a line which should turn the `takeapicdiv` visibility to visible, but it don't also it make my script after this line not to execute and do nothing, I'd really appreciate if somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `takeapicturesnap_div` is a class, not an id.

You can either switch to using id, or use `document.querySelector(".takeapicturesnap_div")`

Comment: `document.querySelector` does the same as `document.querySelectorAll` and index the collection with `0`, so I'd suggest to use it. Anyway, +1 for the required edit

Comment: I wonder sometimes it screw me up in problems like this, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`takeapicturesnap_div` is a `class` but you're trying to get the DOM node using `document.getElementById()`, which won't work.

Try to change the HTML like this..

```
<div class="Takeapicture_div">
    <input type="button" class="takeapicture_btn" id="takeapicture_btn" value="Take a picture"/>
</div>
<div class="takeapicturesnap_div" id="takeapicturesnap_div"> <!-- You can remove class if you don't need -->
    <video id="video" class="profilevideo" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <input type="button" id="snapButton" class="takesnapshoot" value="Capture Image"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you get div element by id while you didn't assign it an id to id!

```
var takeapicdiv = document.getElementById("takeapicturesnap_div");
```

your div only hav a class so you should replace it with

```
<div id="takeapicturesnap_div">
```